Combine BottomNavigation with List - Detail navigation with animations in Jetpack compose
Given a typical app with some bottom bar buttons and sections in which users can navigate from list to detail, ideally I'd like to keep the nice default fade effect for bottom bar transitions, and slide in/out for list-detail transitions. This is my oversimplified relevant code.-
Scaffold(
    ...
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation() {
        }
    }
) { padding ->
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = TabView.Home.route) {
        composable(TabView.Home.route) {
            Home()
        }
        navigation(route = TabView.Browse.route, startDestination = NavigationDestination.Games.route) {
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.GamesList.route) {
                GamesList()                
            }
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.GameDetail.route) {
                GameDetail()
            }
        }
        composable(TabView.Contact.route) {
            ContactForm()
        }
    }
}

my first approach would be to add the wanted animations to my GameDetail route like this.-
enterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(transitionDuration)) },
exitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(transitionDuration)) },
popEnterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(transitionDuration)) },
popExitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(transitionDuration)) }

which works as expected if I open the detail and pop back, but gives undesired result if I tap on a different tab button from the detail (i.e. the home screen appears fading in, BUT the GameDetail disappears with the slide animation).
Is there a simple way to grant that the slide animations would only work when 'pushing' / 'popping' the detail, but not when navigating through the bottom bar?
And more generally, is there a better approach for combining both kind animations? Would it be a better practice to have two independent navControllers?

I ended up using independent NavControllers instead of adding nested navigations inside a single NavHost. It looks like this.-
NavHost(tabNavController, startDestination = TabNavigationDestination.Home.route) {
    composable(route = TabNavigationDestination.Home.route) {
        val homeNavController = rememberNavController()
        currentNavController = homeNavController
        NavHost(homeNavController, startDestination = NavigationDestination.UserProfile.route) {
            composable(
                NavigationDestination.UserProfile.route,
                enterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(transitionDuration)) },
                exitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(transitionDuration)) },
                popEnterTransition = { slideIntoContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(transitionDuration)) },
                popExitTransition = { slideOutOfContainer(AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(transitionDuration)) },
            ) {
                UserProfile()  
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}

Now I have independent in/out animations for every nested NavHost, plus I can check if there's a previousBackStackEntry in the currentNavController in order to show / hide a back button in the top bar (which was tricky following the approach in the question).
It's worth mentioning that I discarded this approach at first, because I needed to know the current route in order to render a dynamic title + back button in the navigation bar, which I solved by adding the currentNavController as state.-
var currentNavController by remember { mutableStateOf<NavController?>(null) }

Not sure if it's the best approach in terms of performance (it might involve extra recomposings), but it definitely works without messing with a lot of issues derived from using a single navController, plus I can also reuse the same composable paths in different tab items (which I couldn't before without making sure every route was different).
More useful information on nested navigation + example project in this video.-
